# Merge two folders with the same tree (auFS)

Tags: ubuntu, mount, aufs

I am trying to merge two folders that contain the same tree and bring them together in a third folder that contains a link to the contents of two different folders, it is possible with auFS?
If this is not possible, is there another solution?

Thank you !

```
dd1
└── 1
    ├── a
    │   └── 1
    ├── b
    ├── c
    │   ├── 1
    │   ├── 2
    │   └── 3
    └── d
        └── 1
dd2   
└── 1
    ├── a
    │   └── 2
    ├── b
    │   └── 1
    ├── c
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── d
        └── 2
```

transform the upper block into the under block

```
www
└── 3
    ├── a
    │   ├── 1
    │   └── 2
    ├── b
    │   └── 1
    ├── c
    │   ├── 1
    │   ├── 2
    │   ├── 3
    │   ├── 4
    │   └── 5
    └── d
        ├── 1
        └── 2
```

dd1 and dd2 are using ***NTFS*** filesystem, and are external drives connected by usb and already auto-mounted in fstab by default at startup.

I have actually this configuration:

```
sudo mount -t aufs -o br=/mnt/dd1/1/:/mnt/dd2/1/ none /var/www/3/
```

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange.com. To improve your question, please remove the introdutory paragraph and directly state your question. Also, please remove the French translation, as English is the language of this site.

Comment: @DanielSerodio Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aufs is very old, the today's variant is [overlayfs](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt).

```
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=/mnt/dd1/1/:/mnt/dd2/1/ /var/www/3/
```

It will be read only.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works perfectly as I wanted !!